# No popup is appearing on onclick event

Tags: javascript, php

Why this code is not working inside PHP? I want to popup a dialog box when a user click on my image which has an id of "1".

```
<script>
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>

$id1 = document.getElementById('1');

$id1.onclick = function() {
  alert('hello');
};

</script>";
```

Comment: you can't use a number as ID on your element. Use something like elem1 or even better something more descriptive

Comment: @PatrickHund you're not right

Comment: OK, I'm surprised you can actually just use digits as IDs. I that's a good practice is another matter

Answer (score 0):

```js
function one() {
 alert('hello');
};
```

```html
<a onClick="one()">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. As opposed to the first comment to your question, you **CAN** use a number as a unique identifier: [Link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID).
>
> There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; ***in
>   particular, IDs can consist of just digits***, start with a digit,
>   start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.
>
> An element's unique identifier can be used for a variety of purposes,
>   most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using
>   fragments, as a way to target an element when scripting, and as a way
>   to style a specific element from CSS.

Just try to put an `input` element with the property `id="1"` and then access it with `document.getElementById` function. It works.

But what I agree with is that such identifies are pretty hard to read, understand and even remember... Just "1" doesn't tell you anything about the element. I wouldn't recommend to use such an approach. Yes, it'd be better to use more "telling" names like "button-for-test" or smth like that.

2. The code isn't working because in context of **PHP tag** you use `$` sign which refers to a variable... PHP variable. So the line `$id1 = document.getElementById('1');` is interpreted as `= document.getElementById('1');` and causes a syntax error for JS. It's first evaluated as a php variable, and because it's not defined, there's nothing to echo, so the js script you want to add to the page, isn't completed.

The source code of that part of the page looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 = document.getElementById('1');
.onclick = function() {
                    alert('hello');
                };
</script>
```

You see that there's no variable itself

Instead of this, try the following combined code:

```
<?php
/*
    If you declare a php variable, the value you assign to it becomes a JS 
    variable name and is echoed then in the script
*/
$id1 = "test";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$id1 = document.getElementById('1');
$id1.onclick = function() {
                alert('hello');
            };
</script>"

?>
```

After that if you look at the source code of the page, you'll see that the variable declaration is correct now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Var name has appeared!
test = document.getElementById('1');
test.onclick = function() {
                    alert('hello');
                };
</script>
```

If you've made no else mistakes in the code, clicking the button should cause alert popup.

3. I'd recommend declare vars as follows:

   var varName = value;

Otherwise the variable automatically becomes global. The way you choose depends on your goals and the program architecture

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dzmtrs. Sorry for the silly mistake. I am new. I know it's not a good idea to put id's as numeric values, but there's a purpose behind it. Anyways, thank you again ^.^

Comment: @wished you're welcome. You can vote my reply up if you want. I want to emphesize that using "1" as an id isn't the root cause of why your code wasn't working

Comment: You're right! I tried to vote you, but I don't have atleast 15 reputation points. Just signed up 2 days ago LOL :)